# Do Domain Events also replace injections of Domain Services into entities?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Quotes are [from](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/)

Note - here I'm using the term "*injecting service into an entity*" for both passing a *service* to *constructor* or passing it as an *argument* to a *method*

a) What is the difference between *handlers* and those *actions/operations* that are also triggered by *domain operations*, but are instead handled within the *domain* itself? Perhaps the difference is that the former ( ie *handlers*, or more precisely their *actions* ) don't represent *domain concepts*, while the latter represent *domain concepts*?

b)

> you do *not* need to inject anything into your domain entities.

Reason for introducing *Domain Events* is so we don't have to inject *services* into *domain entities*. But since injecting *Domain Services* **DS** into *entities* is also not very desirable, couldn't in such cases *handlers* ( ie their *actions* ) be *domain concepts* ( ie instead of injecting **DS** into an *entity*, *handler* would make a call to this **DS** )?

c) If indeed *handlers* could also replace injecting **DSs** into *domain entities*, are there also situations where *handlers* could replace the **DS** itself?

d)

> handler classes do not belong in the domain model.

Do *handlers* belong to the *Infrastructure layer*? What about those *handlers* that call **DS**?

**UPDATE:**

a)

> The central difference is that a domain event handler is invoked after
>   the fact.

But *action/operation* **A** ( the one which we handle within a *domain* and not within a *handler* ) triggered by the *operation* **OP** may also occur after the fact ( ie after **OP** is finished ).So couldn't we argue that main difference between these *two types of actions* is  that **A** represents a *domain concept*, while those *actions* that are performed by *handlers* don't represent *domain concepts*?

b) Just to be sure - so would an answer my original question be that in some cases instead of *entities* calling **DSs**, we can have *handlers* call appropriate **DSs**?

c)

> Domain events can eliminate need for domain services in cases such as
>   above

So answer to **c)** is that in some cases *handlers* can indeed replace **DS**? But if so, couldn't we argue that in such cases *handlers* ( ie their *actions* ) are *domain concepts*?

d)

> Handlers aren't really part of your domain because all they do is
>   delegate to the appropriate infrastructure service or domain service.
>   They are just a form of glue, similar to an application service. They
>   can still be declared in the domain project, but usually they don't
>   need to be.

I.

> Handlers aren't really part of your domain because all they do is
>   delegate to the appropriate infrastructure service or domain service.

Just to be sure - I assume by "delegate to" you mean that instead of *entity* calling appropriate **DS** or *infrastructure service*, we delegate the job of calling a particular *service* to a *handler*?

II.

> They can still be declared in the domain project, but usually they
>   don't need to be.

As you noted in **c)**, in some cases *handlers* can replace the **DS** itself ( ie they don't call a **DS**, but in fact perform the required *operations* by themselves ). In such cases, couldn't we argue that *handlers* are *domain concepts* and as such belong in a *domain layer*?!

**SECOND UPDATE:**

D - II

> > As you noted in c), in some cases handlers can replace the DS itself (
> >     ie they don't call a DS, but in fact perform the required operations
> >     by themselves ). In such cases, couldn't we argue that handlers are
> >     domain concepts and as such belong in a domain layer?!
>
> In those cases I would say that the handler has two responsibilities -
>   that of wiring up the event and performing the operation. The wiring
>   part isn't a domain concept, however the operation itself is.

a) So in those cases *handler* would be violating SRP?

b)

> The wiring part isn't a domain concept, however the operation itself
>   is.

Should in such case *handler* be put into *domain layer*?

2)
Assuming *action* **A** returns a *value*, how do we decide whether it's better to execute **A** by *injecting* ( note - here I'm using the term "*injecting service into an entity*" for both passing a *service* to *constructor* or passing it as *an argument to a method* ) *service* **S** ( which in turn executes **A** ) into an *entity* or to use a *Domain Event* instead ( which in turn would call *methods* on **S** )?

Perhaps decision depends on whether or not some *domain code* needs the result of *A* for some further *processing*?

Comment: Domain events are simply interesting things that have happened in your domain that other systems may be interested in.  You just need some way to expose those events to the other systems.  You *can* use them within your domain but that is not their primary purpose.

Comment: @Eben Roux: So primary purpose of Domain Events is to notify only OTHER systems of interesting things that happened within a domain?

Comment: That is correct.  It may not be the *only* responsibility but is definitely is the primary.  Domains services can probably handle should be able to handle your domain concepts / tasks well enough.

Comment: @Eben Roux "Domains services can probably handle should be able to handle your domain concepts / tasks well enough." I'm not sure I follow your reasoning, since my question wasn't so much whether handler should perform an  action instead of a domain service DS, but more of a whether handler should invoke DS instead of us injecting that DS into an entity?!

Comment: That will come down to preference but passing in the DS to an entity method is fine and that is what I would probably do.

Comment: @Eben Roux: May I just ask why you think it's better to pass DS to an entity method rather than using Domain Event to call methods on DS (  I guess this question could also be expanded into "why do you think Domain Events should only be used to notify other systems of interesting events" )?

Comment: A domain event is something interesting that took place *in the domain*.  So this implies that the domain knows how to do what it does (probably why domain events don't have a mention in the blue book).  Other systems may be interested in what takes place in a domain also; hence a domain event is the relevant mechanism.  If you are using a DE as an intra-domain communication mechanism it is no longer a business/domain concern but rather becomes a technical one.  That being said, when using a DE mechanism as an internal event bus and it works then that too is fine.  Just my ZAR 0.02 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a) The central difference is that a domain event handler is invoked after the fact. The event has already occurred and is immutable. Therefore, the handled can only do things in response to something that has already happened. Moreover, a handler can cause behavior that isn't part of the responsibility of the source entity, such as sending an email.

b) Domain events are a pattern for ensuring a greater degree of encapsulation and decoupling. For example, the fact that an email should be sent after some action can be implemented in a few ways. One way is to pass an email service to an entity. The entity would then call the email service when needed. Another way is to have the calling application service call the email service. The problem with the first approach is that now the entity is coupled to the email service and violates SRP - the domain is now dealing with technical issues. The problem with the second approach is that it places the responsibility of knowing when to send an email on the application service. Domain events address both of these issues since now the entity decides when the event occurs and the handlers decide what to do with the event.

c) Domain events can eliminate need for domain services in cases such as above, however they don't eliminate need for domain services in all cases. There are cases where an entity may need a domain service in order to invoke behavior in the first place. This is where domain events can't help since they only address after-the fact scenarios.

d) Handlers aren't really part of your domain because all they do is delegate to the appropriate infrastructure service or domain service. They are just a form of glue, similar to an application service. They can still be declared in the domain project, but usually they don't need to be.

**UPDATE**

a) That is not always the case. It is acceptable for a domain event handler to invoke another domain operation. This is a way of doing event-driven architecture within a single process.

b) Yes, a domain event handler can invoke a domain service. Having a handler call a domain service in response to an event is a way to add behaviors to entities in a decoupled way - a form of the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

c) Normally, a handler would delegate to something in order to perform a domain operation. The handler itself is only the glue. However, you can place domain logic into the handler in which case it would act like a domain service.

d1) Yes. A handler would be a simple class with a constructor dependency on some service. When it handles an event it calls the appropriate method on said service.

d2) In those cases I would say that the handler has two responsibilities - that of wiring up the event and performing the operation. The wiring part isn't a domain concept, however the operation itself is.

**UPDATE 2**

a) Yes I would say so. Depending on how your domain events are implemented, the handler could just be a lambda - it doesn't need to be a class.

b) If the handler is delegating to domain services then it can go into the domain layer. If it makes use of infrastructural services, it may need to go into the infrastructure layer. Also, as stated in a), the handler doesn't need to be a class, it could be a lambda.

2) A domain event is something notable that *happened* in the domain. Use a domain event where you can envision subscribers being interested in that event. This event can be used to invoke additional behavior in the domain or to be published externally. The main observation is that it is an immutable event in the past tense.

> Perhaps decision depends on whether or not some domain code needs the
>   result of A for some further processing?

This is true. If a domain operation needs the result of a domain service S in order to continue executing its behavior then that service should be passed to that behavioral method. An entity cannot receive the result of processing of a published domain event.